# How to list files and folders backed up by Deja Dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I'm using Deja Dup to back up my data to Google Drive. Would like to know how to list all files & folders that are currently backed up. I don't think it's possible through the GUI, so I'm wondering how to do it through the terminal, perhaps with duplicity?

Answer (score 2):

To list all files in a backup

```
duplicity list-current-files --time 1D file:[location of your backup]
```

Comment: Not sure how to provide the location of my backup in Google Drive, I just copy-pasted the URL of the latest archive and got this error: `InvalidBackendURL: missing // - relative paths not supported for scheme file`

Comment: Then I tried downloading the archive and providing the absolute path. Now I'm getting this error: `Attempt 1 failed. NotADirectoryError: Not a directory`

I guess it's expecting a directory?

Comment: I don't use the google drive option but I will try to figure out how to do that. Yes, it wants the directory you are backing up to.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably rather something along the lines

```
GOOGLE_DRIVE_ACCOUNT_KEY=~/.gdrive.pem
duplicity list-current-files pydrive://<service account' email address>@developer.gserviceaccount.com/some_dir
```

or

```
GOOGLE_DRIVE_SETTINGS=~/.gdrive.conf
duplicity list-current-files pydrive:///some_dir
```

depending on what type of access you activate. i'd suggest the user variant, as it is a little simpler.

visit https://duplicity.gitlab.io/duplicity-web/vers8/duplicity.1.html and see section **'A NOTE ON PYDRIVE BACKEND'** on how to set up pydrive access to google drive with duplicity.

Comment: I don't have a `.gdrive` file

Comment: @Fadi  did you read the linked man page section? it explains how to create the needed file.